# Need help onSolrUtils::escapeQueryChars() usage

Tags: php, solr, pecl

I want some real life scenario in programming where we can use this solr util method i.e. SolrUtils::escapeQueryChars().

Now I am using it for escaping query chars from query in solr.

> **q:+popularity:[10   TO   *]     +section:0**

And I am using

> **escapeQueryChars(+popularity:[10   TO   *]     +section:0)**

But I am unable to get the result after escaping.

Answer (score 1):

SolrUtils::escapeQueryChars is usually used to escape characters in the Query which have special meaning in Solr.

The current list of characters are `+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \` which have special meaning in Solr and the behaviour would be different if not escaped.

for example if you are searching for `5*` unless escaped it would behave as a wildcard search and return results with tokens starting from `5`.

Answer (score 0):

It shall be used in query **values** only.

Most of the time you will be accepting queries from a user. So its essential to escape these characters to avoid exceptions

a user search query can be: "Thomas' Calculus (12th Edition)"
The user query above would certainly lead to unwanted results

```
$query = new SolrQuery('product_name:'.SolrUtils::escapeQueryChars($userQuery));
```